# Handling missing data with numpy to concentrate different shape arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, missing-data

So I decided to get a little more into numpy but my original data comes from a dataframe, let's say for now this is the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'col1': [101, 200, 306, 402, 500, 600],
'col2': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]})
```

I want to perform some basic column based calculations and save then in the same order inside of a numpy array, so I turn it into a numpy 2d array like this:

```
arr = np.array(df['col1'] - df['col2']).reshape((-1, 1))
    # out
[[1]
 [0]
 [6]
 [2]
 [0]
 [0]]
```

But then let's say my dataframe updates and the values of `col1` become `col2` and so the new values are added to `col1` and zeroes are added to `col2` if the value didn't exist before:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'col1': [103, 220, 316, 406, 501, 606, 348],
'col2': [101, 200, 306, 402, 500, 600, 0]})
```

So now instead of 6 values I have 7 which is where the complications start, since I want to calculate this difference as well and append it in the order it is to the array, so I tried to do this:

```
arr1 = np.array(df['col1'] - df['col2']).reshape((-1, 1))
arr = np.append(arr, np.zeros((len(arr1 - arr), arr.shape[0])), axis=1)
```

In order to fill the missing values and allow for concentration of both arrays, but it throws
a : `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,1) (6,1)`

I appreciate any help!

**Full code and expected output**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'col1': [101, 200, 306, 402, 500, 600],
'col2': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]})

arr = np.array(df['col1'] - df['col2']).reshape((-1, 1))

df = pd.DataFrame({
'col1': [103, 220, 316, 406, 501, 606, 348],
'col2': [101, 200, 306, 402, 500, 600, 0]})

arr1 = np.array(df['col1'] - df['col2']).reshape((-1, 1))

arr = np.append(arr, np.zeros((len(arr1 - arr), arr.shape[1])), axis=0)

arr = np.concatenate((arr, arr1), axis=1)

##EXPECTED##

[[1   2]
 [0  20]
 [6  10]
 [2   4]
 [0   1]
 [0   6]
 [0 348]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of the `np.append` -

1. Create `np.zeros((difference in shape[0], arr.shape[1]))`
2. `np.vstack` the arr and the zeros
3. Concatenate arr, arr1

```
arr = np.vstack([arr, np.zeros((arr1.shape[0] - arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1]))]) #<--------

arr = np.concatenate((arr, arr1), axis=1)

print(arr)
```

```
# [[1   2]
#  [0  20]
#  [6  10]
#  [2   4]
#  [0   1]
#  [0   6]
#  [0 348]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have also found the issue, just syntax...